# Still reachable memory in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks

i have the following result after i use valgrind to check for memory leaks.

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==10299==   in use at exit: 2,286 bytes in 68 blocks
==10299==   total heap usage: 139 allocs, 71 frees, 164,646 bytes allocated
==10299== 
==10299== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10299==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10299==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10299==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10299==    still reachable: 2,286 bytes in 68 blocks
==10299==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10299== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==10299== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==10299== 
==10299== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10299== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

My aim is try to make it memory leak is not possible. i know that i have to free the the memory after i use malloc function. but even so, it still give me the same result. Hence, i need help to see is there anything wrong with my coding.

below is my code.

```
 struct date
{   int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

Date *date_create(char *datestr)
{       
    //declare Date to pointer from datestr and check the data size of Date
    Date *pointer = (Date *) malloc (sizeof(Date));

    if(pointer!=NULL)
    {
        scanf(datestr,"%2d/%2d/%4d",pointer->day,pointer->month,pointer->year);
    }
        else
    {
          printf("Error! ");
      date_destroy(pointer);

    }
        return pointer;

}

void date_destroy(Date *d)
{

    free(d);
}


int main(){
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Is this really the code you ran through valgrind? That code does nothing because the `main` function just returns. So it's hard to believe that valgrind would produce that report for the given code. And the code is definetely not complete - `Date` is not a defined type.

Comment: Please post a MCVE. And check that `int main() {}` does not give errors.

Comment: `scanf()` --> `sscanf()`, `Date` is undefined, and your `main()` does nothing.

Comment: Following valgrind's suggestion to rerun valgrind as `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all` usually helps you to figure out where the leaks are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call your function from main then valgrind will show you memory leak in your code. You should not cast malloc. If you have successfully allocate memory then only you will able to free it. You need to change code like this

```
Date *date_create(char *datestr)
{       
    //declare Date to pointer from datestr and check the data size of Date
    Date *pointer =  malloc (sizeof (Date));

    if(pointer!=NULL)
    {
        scanf(datestr,"%2d/%2d/%4d",pointer->day,pointer->month,pointer->year);
    }
        else
    {
          printf("Error! ");
     // date_destroy(pointer); Not required

    }
    if(pointer) { // Free the allocated memory after use
        date_destroy(pointer); 
    }
        return pointer;

}
```

Comment: It is OK to free a null pointer, so that part of the code does not need modification

Comment: @M.M it's ok but still he need to add part of memory free and free(NULL) doesn't do anything then  why should we do free()?

Comment: @KimMcWingWee great...How u solved? If because of this then click on accept answer.

Comment: similar to your code just that, i add in a free(pointer) at the end

Comment: @KimMcWingWee great ...then click on accept answer on left side .

Answer (score 0):

Your code is set to `free` the pointer when `malloc` returns `NULL`, but `free(NULL)` doesn't do anything.

You need to call `free()` after you're finished using the pointer.

```
int main(void) {
    char datestr[64];
    Date* dptr;

    fgets(datestr, sizeof(datestr), stdin);

    dptr = date_create(datestr);

    /* do some stuff with Date ptr */

    free(dptr); /* now call free */

    return 0;
}
```

Also, in your `date_create()` function, you use `scanf`, when I think you want to use `sscanf`.

So this line

```
scanf(datestr,"%2d/%2d/%4d",pointer->day,pointer->month,pointer->year);
```

becomes

```
sscanf(datestr,"%2d/%2d/%4d",pointer->day,pointer->month,pointer->year);
```